# ArcGIS Network Analyst and modelBuilder problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I need to use server tool Create Service Areas. For input data i need to use iteration of features, that uses as Facilities. Task in general - to create service area. Area radius depends on count of people, living in area. Radius of area increases iterativly while it exceeds Threshold value. Model works properly for one Facility, but when I try to use iterator for feature selection as Facilities it crushes with error Facilities: dataset does not exist or does not supported"

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your model and any code that you might have to help us get a better grasp on your question?

Comment: i've added a screenshot

Comment: See this Q&A  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160094/using-iterate-feature-selection-export-features-to-new-feature-class-with-unique

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i can't understand - where should I add inline variable? Iterator output does not support other data types, except 'vector_layer'